# Linker issue when using OpenGL on VS 2017

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors

On Windows, I set up *Visual Studio 2017* for *OpenGL* and added *Includes* and *Libraries* folders (dedicated for OpenGl_Stuff) to *Include Directories* and *Library Directories* and also *glfw3.lib* *opengl32.lib* to *Additional Dependencies*, all to the *Properties* of the project

Then created an *Empty Project* named *opengl_1* for running [this](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/1.1.hello_window/hello_window.cpp) and [this](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/2.1.hello_triangle/hello_triangle.cpp) codes. They ran successfully.

But there is an issue.
I get these 13 linker errors:

> *Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _gl3wInit referenced in
>   function _main    Opengl_1    C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj 1*
>
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _LoadShaders referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ) Opengl_1
>   C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj 1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _gl3wDrawArrays  Opengl_1 
>   C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj 1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _gl3wBindBuffer  Opengl_1 
>   C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj 1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
>   _gl3wEnableVertexAttribArray  Opengl_1 C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj 1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _gl3wUseProgram  Opengl_1 
>   C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj 1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
>   _gl3wVertexAttribPointer  Opengl_1  C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj 1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _gl3wClearBufferfv   Opengl_1 
>   C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj   1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _gl3wBindVertexArray Opengl_1
>   C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj 1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _gl3wGenVertexArrays Opengl_1
>   C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj  1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
>   _gl3wCreateBuffers    Opengl_1    C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj    1*
>
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
>   _gl3wNamedBufferStorage   Opengl_1    C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Opengl_1\Main.obj    1*
>
> Error LNK1120 12 unresolved
>   externals Opengl_1    C:\Users\Abbasi\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Opengl_1\Debug\Opengl_1.exe 1*

When I want to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"

enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers };
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0 };
GLuint VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint Buffers[NumBuffers];
const GLuint NumVertices = 6;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// init
//
void
init(void)
{
    static const GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][2] =
    {
        { -0.90, -0.90 }, // Triangle 1
        { 0.85, -0.90 },
        { -0.90, 0.85 },
        { 0.90, -0.85 }, // Triangle 2
        { 0.90, 0.90 },
        { -0.85, 0.90 }
    };
    glCreateBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
    glNamedBufferStorage(Buffers[ArrayBuffer], sizeof(vertices),
        vertices, 0);
    ShaderInfo shaders[] = {
        { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert" },
        { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag" },
        { GL_NONE, NULL }
    };
    GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
    glUseProgram(program);
    glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// display
//
void
display(void)
{
    static const float black[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// main
//
int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Triangles", NULL,
        NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gl3wInit();
    init();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        display();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

How to solve this please?

Comment: `gl3wInit` is neither from OpenGL directly nor from glfw. If you want to use it, link against the library where it comes from. It also seems that you don't have an implementation of the LoadShader method in your project.

Comment: please copy/paste the error message. otherwise your question cannot be correctly indexed and is helpless for other users facing the same issue

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: sorry for inconvenient. I edited the question.

Comment: @BDL: The book *OpenGL.Programming.Guide.9th.Edition* declares this code in page 40 as *Example1.1*.

Comment: If possible, please test that code on your Visual Studio to know if the issue is related to the code or VS.

Comment: I solved the problem, and will provide an answer soon for those who have that problem too.